# RStudio Server Can't Find 'GLIBCXX_3.4.20'

Tags: rstudio-server

I've got a server running RStudio, and recently another user updated what version of gcc was on it for another project. I attempted to install Rcpp, and get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcpp’ in dyn.load(file,
>   DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object
>   '/home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
>   /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by
>   /home/username/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.5/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so)
>   Error: loading failed Execution halted ERROR: loading failed

Oddly, this doesn't occur when using R from the command line, which makes me think that RStudio Server is having trouble *finding* GLIBCXX_3.4.20, rather than it being genuinely missing.

Does anyone know how to sort this error out?